# Error Syntax on Mysql Function

Tags: mysql, function

Would like to know what is the error on this syntax since all the sample given is similar with the 1 i try to create

```
CREATE FUNCTION test(regionCode varchar(5)) RETURNS CHAR(50)
DETERMINISTIC
READ SQL DATA
BEGIN
DECLARE NAME_FOUND CHAR(50);
SELECT 'abc' into NAME_FOUND from dual;
RETURN NAME_FOUND;
END
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: what is the error .. don't ask us to guess. Also, this is more likely Oracle syntax instead of MySQL

Comment: its syntax error like i mentioned not much info is given. SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'READ SQL DATABEGINDECLARE NAME_FOUND CHAR(50)' at line 3.

Comment: @Ravi I dont think its an Oracle, I created a lot of Oracle function but this is my first time seeing keyword such Deterministic and Read Sql Data. My reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html

Comment: "READS SQL DATA" not "READ SQL DATA"

Comment: @BillKarwin oh my god, a very silly mistake thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mysql Functin having only READS SQL DATA not READ SQL DATA,that is the mistake you have done in your function.Please find the link for more details:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-programs-logging.html

READS SQL DATA explicitly tells to MySQL that the function will ONLY read data from databases, thus, it does not contain instructions that modify data, but it contains SQL instructions that read data (e.q. SELECT).

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION test(regionCode varchar(5)) RETURNS CHAR(50)
DETERMINISTIC
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
DECLARE NAME_FOUND CHAR(50);
SELECT 'abc' into NAME_FOUND from dual;
RETURN NAME_FOUND;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 CREATE FUNCTION test(regionCode varchar(5)) RETURNS CHAR(50)

READS SQL DATA
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
DECLARE NAME_FOUND CHAR(50);
SELECT 'abc' into NAME_FOUND from dual;
RETURN NAME_FOUND;
END
```

TRY THIS QUERY